# Shutil zipping error and shutil rmtree error, help me understand

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, zip, shutil

```
source = r'C:/Users/murph/Desktop/scrape/themeforest/zipping/in/'
destin = r'C:/Users/murph/Desktop/DONE/'
print('Preparing to zip files now. . . . ')
files = os.listdir(source)
for f in files:
    shutil.make_archive(f, "zip", source)
    shutil.rmtree(f)
    print(f + "done")
    break
shutil.move(source,destin)
```

What i understand when i was writing this, i am declaring source and final destination for my zip files, i create a for loop to check how many folders ready for zipping, zips the file, removes the original folder before zipping and throw the finished zip file into the new destination. the last part is me trying to see whats wrong after everything infront went wrong.

what i got is files are zipped together, 2 the folders are inside 1 zip file, original folders not deleting by itself and remains there, finished zip file does not end up in destination i specified but instead saved into where my current script is residing.

Please help by explaining what i coded wrong.

Comment: i tried your method by assigning files = os.path.listdir(source) but gotten error, or maybe explain more what should i change

Comment: `listdir` only return the basename of the file in the target directory, and by using any of the names directly it will look in the current working directory (default is the same as where the running script is, which is exactly what you are reporting).  Please read the provided solution, specifically the second part where it used `os.path.join` - you may need to do `os.path.join(source, f)` to get the correct full path.

Comment: noted with thanks, i think i know where i went wrong.